# Migrating Microsoft Graph Api alerts_v1 to alerts_v2

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

*Without given code*

I work for a company that is looking to switch from using Microsoft Graph API alerts_v1 to alerts_v2.

I have developed a script that works successfully for the v1 version. However, the script that I build for the v2 version doesn't fully work, I encounter an authentication error that occurs during the testing phase.

The error message indicates that the application is missing certain application roles that are necessary for the API to operate correctly. These required roles include SecurityAlert.Read.All, SecurityAlert.ReadWrite.All, SecurityIncident.Read.All, SecurityIncident.ReadWrite.All, as well as application roles like SecurityActions.ReadWrite.All, SecurityEvents.Read.All, ThreatIndicators.ReadWrite.OwnedBy, SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All, SecurityActions.Read.All, and AuditLog.Read.All.

I have been unable to find any helpful information about why these roles are necessary through online searches, and I am hoping someone can provide me with more guidance on this issue.

Output of the runned script:
`{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Missing application roles. API required roles: SecurityAlert.Read.All,SecurityAlert.ReadWrite.All,SecurityIncident.Read.All,SecurityIncident.ReadWrite.All, application roles: SecurityActions.ReadWrite.All,SecurityEvents.Read.All,ThreatIndicators.ReadWrite.OwnedBy,SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All,SecurityActions.Read.All,AuditLog.Read.All.","innerError":{"date":"2023-05-03T11:51:41","request-id":"11111-11111-11111-1111","client-request-id":"111111-111111-1111111-11111"}}} [{'ERROR': 403}]`

In an attempt to resolve the authentication error that occurs when testing the Microsoft Graph API alerts_v2 with a script that previously worked for alerts_v1, I have tried testing different parts of the script to see if I can gather more information. I was hoping to find some useful output that could help me configure the config file for the tenant ID, among other things.

Additionally, I have conducted extensive online searches to learn more about the migration process and the alerts_v2 functionality, as the Microsoft documentation for the Graph API can be difficult to navigate. Unfortunately, my efforts have not yielded any helpful information so far.

My primary goal is to gain a better understanding of why the application requires such extensive permissions and how I might be able to prevent this from happening in the future to ensure the application works as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is just one of the generic Graph permission error messages which some Graph endpoints give out. The actual permissions you need depends on the Endpoint your using eg if you just listing event

```
GET /security/alerts_v2
```

and you where going with the least permission model then SecurityAlert.Read.All is what you would need the documented for each specific endpoint should be correct https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-list-alerts_v2?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

For other endpoint like

```
GET /security/incidents
```

you would need SecurityIncident.Read.All

The error your getting back is because they just do a catch all for /security when there is an permission error rather then validate each role in your current token (just return a generic error message) and what is required for that endpoint. This is generally where you want to start your troubleshooting process by verifying what in the current roles are in your using via jwt.io and then you need to read the documentation for the endpoint you want to access which will tell you what the minimum permission is required. I know you trying to migrate something but IMO your better treating this as a new app/piece of code your going to be running against the Graph. If its a script you should be able to isolate your testing so each function or cmdlet does a specific task against a Graph endpoint.

Comment: Hi first of al thank you for your response. I assume the permissions of alerts_v1 is the same set as alerts_v2? Or did I completely over read that in documentation? 

Cheers :)

Comment: It depends which endpoint you accessing without seeing the code you using there is now one to say one way or the other. But the first thing you should do it confirm the access token your using in jwt.io then you can be sure what roles are set. I did a quick test against /security/alerts_v2 and all that was needed was SecurityAlert.Read.All . Treat it as a new script and don't make any assumptions in my advice and then test to see why it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you again for your reaction I will try this method and hopefully with positive result.

Cheers!